# Sound overlapping with multiple button clicks

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.tobiadegoroye.pokemonsoundboard;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class PokemonSoundboard extends AppCompatActivity {


    MediaPlayer psyduckplayer; //member variable
    MediaPlayer pikachuplayer; //member variable
    MediaPlayer diglettplayer; //member variable



    ImageButton mpsyduckbutton;
    ImageButton mpikachubutton;
    ImageButton mdiglettbutton;

    View.OnClickListener psyducklistner = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            psyduckplayer.start();

        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener pikachulistner = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pikachuplayer.start();

        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener digletlistner = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            diglettplayer.start();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pokemon_soundboard);


        mpsyduckbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.psyduckbutton);
        mpikachubutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pikachubutton);
        mdiglettbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.diglettbutton);

        psyduckplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.psyduck);
        pikachuplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.pikachu);
        diglettplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.diglett);

        mpsyduckbutton.setOnClickListener(psyducklistner);
        mpikachubutton.setOnClickListener(pikachulistner);
        mdiglettbutton.setOnClickListener(digletlistner);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MediaPlayer.isPlaying()` and `MediaPlayer.stop()` methods.

```
public void stopPlaying()
{
    if(pikachuplayer != null && pikachuplayer.isPlaying())
    {
            pikachuplayer.stop();
    }
    if(digletplayer != null && digletplayer.isPlaying())
    {
            digletplayer.stop();
    }
    if(psyduckplayer != null && psyduckplayer.isPlaying())
    {
            psyduckplayer.stop();
    }
}

View.OnClickListener psyducklistner = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        stopPlaying();
        psyduckplayer.start();

    }
};

View.OnClickListener pikachulistner = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        stopPlaying();
        pikachuplayer.start();

    }
};

View.OnClickListener digletlistner = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        stopPlaying();
        diglettplayer.start();
    }
};

View.OnClickListener digletlistner = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        diglettplayer.start();
    }
};
```

The `stopPlaying()` method stops all Medias from playing, only if they're playing and not `null` (They probably aren't `null`, as they're member variables, but it's still a good practice).

Comment: @Tobi Adegoroye You're welcome. And here at SO, it's a common practice to upvote answers you deem helpful, and even mark them so. There's no obligation to do this, but it does help SO users to grow and rise through the ranks. Welcome to the Community!